# ip address 0.0.0.0 in access logs

Tags: codeigniter, expressionengine

One of the admins of a site we are maintaining is unable to log into the CP after i upgraded EE to 2.5.3

What I am seeing in the acces logs, is that before, she always (succesfully) logged in from the ip address 0.0.0.0. I guess she still tries to log in from this ip now, but EE blocks this.

Is there something I can do, or is the issue caused by her local situation?

Comment: This is probably better suited for ServerFault.

Comment: Can you provide more information as to any error message shown when she tries and logs into CP? What is the behaviour on the login page if no error message shown? Does it refresh? Have you had her clear her cookies or try and login from a different browser?

Comment: she doesn't get any message, only the login screen is reloaded. nothing gets registered in the acces logs. And yes, i had her clear cookies and cache. restart het pc too. Other browsers doesn't matter. On her mac she can acces from the same location. Maybe her pc doesn't get an ip from her dhcp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to Admin ➔ Security & Privacy ➔ Security & Sessions have you got 'require IP address' enabled? If so, disabling that should do the trick.

That said, rather than disabling security features, you would likely be better off looking into why her IP address is not being detected. The underlying problem is probably a local one rather than an issue with EE.